# CSS Variables Not Updating on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I'm using Javascript to set the value of CSS variables to a random number every half second and displaying the data as a pie chart, as seen in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjNmkQ), which works fine on my desktop browser, but doesn't seem to update on Mobile Safari. I've read that SCSS might be able to provide functionality but I'd rather keep the solution purely css and javascript if possible.

Css:

```
#CPUPie {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: yellowgreen;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #655 0);
    color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
#CPUPie::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 50%;
    width: 50%; height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
    background-color: inherit;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateZ(var(--CPUPiePercent));
    background: var(--CPUPieBackground);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var CPUPie = document.createElement("div");
CPUPie.id = "CPUPie";
document.body.appendChild(CPUPie);

setInterval(update, 500);
update();
function update() {
    var CPUPiePercent = Math.random();
    if (CPUPiePercent > .5 && CPUPiePercent != 1) {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--CPUPiePercent", (CPUPiePercent - .5) + "turn");
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--CPUPieBackground", "#655");
    }
    else {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--CPUPiePercent", CPUPiePercent + "turn");
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--CPUPieBackground", "yellowgreen");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of iOS? I am pretty sure only recently (9.3+) did they add support for CSS variables.

Comment: I'm running 9.3.3, and the CodePen doesn't work on my phone. And the variable works, but it won't update, so it only shows the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Support for CSS variables is still pretty shaky. I'd recommend storing/updating the variables in the javascript and just set them as such.

Since you're just toggle the background on the before pseudo element, I'd just change that to two different classes

```
#CPUPie.brown::before {
    background-color: #655;
}

#CPUPie.green::before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Then use your javascript like this:

```
if (CPUPiePercent > .5 && CPUPiePercent != 1) {
    document.querySelector('#CPUPie').style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((CPUPiePercent - .5) * 360) + 'deg';
    document.querySelector('#CPUPie').classList.remove('yellowgreen');
    document.querySelector('#CPUPie').classList.add('brown');
}
else {
    document.querySelector('#CPUPie').style.transform = 'rotate(' + (CPUPiePercent * 360) + 'deg';
    document.querySelector('#CPUPie').classList.add('yellowgreen');
    document.querySelector('#CPUPie').classList.remove('brown');
}
```

Comment: That rotates the element, I'm trying to rotate the psuedo element.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in my case by simply creating a new div with similar properties to the pseudo element and layering that on top of the CPUPie. Updated CodePen can be found [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXyJLN).

CSS

```
#CPUPie {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: yellowgreen;
background-image:
  linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #655 0);
color: transparent;
text-align: center;
}

#CPUPieSlice {
position: absolute;
left: 57.5px;
width: 50px; height: 100px;
border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
background-color: transparent;
transform-origin: left;
}
```

JS

```
var CPUPie = document.createElement("div");
CPUPie.id = "CPUPie";
document.body.appendChild(CPUPie);
var CPUPieSlice = document.createElement("div");
CPUPieSlice.id = "CPUPieSlice";
document.body.appendChild(CPUPieSlice);

setInterval(update, 500);
update();
function update() {
  var CPUPiePercent = Math.random();
  if (CPUPiePercent > .5 && CPUPiePercent != 1) {
    document.getElementById("CPUPieSlice").style.transform = "rotate(" + (CPUPiePercent - .5) + "turn)";
    document.getElementById("CPUPieSlice").style.background = "#655";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("CPUPieSlice").style.transform = "rotate(" + CPUPiePercent + "turn)";
    document.getElementById("CPUPieSlice").style.background = "yellowgreen";
  }
}
```